# A new session is created when doing href from one jsp page to another and session variables are returned as null

Tags: java, jsp, session-variables

on first jsp page i have -

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:10pt;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:#ff9900;
    }
</style>

<%
   session.setAttribute( "theName", "abc" );
%>
<li><a href="http://localhost:8080/auto/second.jsp" target="content">click here!!</a></li><br />
</body>
</html>
```

on second.jsp, i have,

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
 <head>
Hello, <%out.print(session.getAttribute( "theName" )); %>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But here the value of session variable "`theName`" is returned as null.
I also did a `<% out.print( session.getId()); %>`on both the first and second pages and the issue is that two different session ids are returned like -
`230EC6DA6ECD25BC96268942D0ACE5EB` (on first page)
`C2399D151F0D6D6002D16A126EDDC9FB` (on second page)

This seems to be the reason that session variable is not getting passed successfully. I also tried putting

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

so that a new session is not created in second.jsp. But if i use `<%@ page session="false" %>`in second.jsp, then it throws jasper exception -

```
Jul 23, 2012 5:23:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 32
<%out.print(session.getAttribute( "theName" ));
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:307)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:565)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:311)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:843)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:679)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1303)
```

Kindly suggest as how can I pass session variables from one jsp page to another. Thanks in advance for any help !!

Comment: `<%@ page session="false" %>` means *don't use a session at all*, not *don't create a new session but use any existing one lying around*.

Comment: You can add your session id to your link as a `JSESSSIONID` parameter.

Comment: @T.J. - how can I achieve that? Because I think that a new session is created by default in a new JSP page.? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Amir - how can I use that same session id then?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled in your browser? If not, then you need to enable them, or encode your URLs properly.

Comment: @JB - cookies are already enabled.

Comment: @anujin: *"Because I think that a new session is created by default in a new JSP page.?"* It shouldn't be, no.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your JSP/servlet engine is expecting to use URL-rewriting rather than using cookies, for the session ID, for whatever reason. If you use [`encodeURL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL%28java.lang.String%29) to output the link to the `second.jsp` page, e.g.:

```
<a href="<%=response.encodeURL("second.jsp")%>">second page</a>
```

...you should find that it ends up being `second.jsp;jsessionid=longstringhere`.

Now, you could use `encodeURL` all over the place, but my guess is you'd rather use cookies. You'll need to check the configuration of your JSP/servlet engine. In Tomcat, [the default is to use cookies](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html), but you might check your `Context` element to make sure it doesn't have `cookies="false"` on it or something...

Comment: i used - `<a href="<%=response.encodeURL("http://localhost:8080/auto/second.jsp")%>" target="content">click here!!</a>` but no luck. it redirects to second.jsp but no `longstringhere` is added to the second.jsp url :(

Comment: @anujin: Why is there a fully-qualified path on that? Is it on a different server? If it's on a different server, that's why there is a new session getting created. If it isn't, use a *relative* URL.